# Limacon/cardioid orientation confusion

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

I'm learning about polar equations and am trying to graph the curve r = 3 + 3 sin(theta), with theta between 0 and 2pi.

Based on what I've learned and the image below, since a = b = 3, it would seem as though the graph should be a cardioid with the indentation pointing to the side (a sideways heart, if you will). However, in Desmos, the graph seems to be like a one-loop limacon (an upside-down heart). What is causing this discrepancy? What rule can I use to determine the orientation of limacons and cardioids if the first image is not correct? Or, is Desmos incorrect in this case?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The "one-loop limacon" in the above picture is misleading. For $a>0, b>0, 1<a/b<2$, it is like a cardioid, but the "dip" smooth and less deep (for example, plot $r=4+3cos\theta$). On the other hand, try to find the pattern of orientation by plotting the following cardioids: $r=3-3sin\theta$, $r=3+3cos\theta$, $r=3-3cos\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ are shifted from each other by an angle of $\frac \pi 2$. So you have to expect that $r = a \pm b\cos\theta$ and $r = a \pm b\sin\theta$ are going to be rotated by a right angle from each other. Also $r = a + b\sin\theta$ surely cannot look exactly like $r=a - b\sin\theta$. The first will have its maximum radius of $a + b$ at $\theta = \frac \pi2$ and its minimum radius of $a - b$ at $\theta = \frac {3\pi}2$. The latter will have them at the exact opposite points.

In other words, what that image is showing is only the *shapes* of the curves, not their orientations. The curves will always have the $x$ or $y$-axis as an axis of symmetry, but that still leaves four possible orientations, and all four are possible in each case, depending on whether you choose $\sin \theta$ or $\cos \theta$ and on whether the coefficient of the trig function is positive or negative. If you want to see curves whose symmetry axis is not the $x$ or $y$ axis, then you introduce a phase factor: $$r = a + b\sin(\theta - \theta_0)$$

I suggest you enter that equation into Desmos and set $a, b, \theta_0$ on sliders. See how the curve behaves as you change each of the values. It will help your intuition.